# Existe algo equivalente ao "FOR UPDATE" do MySQL no SQLite?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Como o próprio título já diz, existe algo equivalente ao `FOR UPDATE` do MySQL no SQLite?

#### Exemplo:

```
SELECT id FROM minha_tabela WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE
```

Possuo uma *query* que utiliza um bloqueio de linha exclusivo dentro de uma transação no MySQL e gostaria de saber se existe uma alternativa que obtivesse o mesmo efeito utilizando o SQLite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, e não faz sentido ter. O SQLite trabalha com transações de escrita exclusivas, portanto só pode haver uma escrita de cada vez e todo o banco de dados é bloqueado para operações de escrita em cada escrita que queira fazer, e ao mesmo tempo não precisa de nenhuma preocupação com as leituras que ocorrem sem nenhum controle especial, e essa é a beleza do SQLite. Não havendo simultaneidade não tem porque existir essa cláusula que é para lidar com problema de compartilhamento.